# Write a "curried version" of a lambda expression

Tags: haskell, lambda, currying

I'm studying Haskell and am trying to understand how to applying the concept of currying to functions. I understand the currying is essentially a means of taking a function with several arguments and applying the function to one argument, returning a function that is applied to the second, and so on... without losing any expressiveness. One tutorial I'm working on asks:

"Write a curried version of `2 * (\x y -> x*y)2 3`"

I'm hoping someone can help show me how to work this out. Thanks in advance

Edit: In response to two commenters, I can see that recognising

`(\x y -> x*y) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`

... is my first step. I have a fairly slow learning curve when it comes to functional programming (also new SO poster so excuse any etiquette I break) ... what would my next step be?

Edit 2: @Mikhail, I see that `uncurry` applied to the type of the lambda expression would something of the form (given `uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a,b) -> c`)

```
Num a => (a,a) -> a
```

Comment: Start by answering a simpler question: what is the type of `(\x y -> x*y)`?

Comment: Int -> Int -> Int ? or Num a => a -> a -> a

Comment: The latter. But the former will do too for this purpose.

Comment: @Steve Now look at the type of the standard function [`uncurry`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:uncurry) and try to work out what is the type of the expression `uncurry (\x y -> x * y)`.

Comment: The last step is to create a lambda expression that has the type you just gave: `(Int, Int) -> Int`.  In other words, instead of accepting two arguments in succession, it now takes a pair of arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your basic understanding of what currying is is correct. Concretely, it is about transforming a function that takes its arguments as a tuple, such as for example

```
add :: (Int, Int) -> Int
add    (x, y)     =  x + y
```

into a function that takes its arguments one at a time:

```
add' :: Int -> Int -> Int
add'    x      y   =  x + y
```

This scheme allows you to subject the now-curried function to *partial application*, i.e., applying it with some but not all of its arguments yet. For example we can have

```
succ :: Int -> Int
succ =  add' 1
```

where we apply `add'` to its first argument and yield a function that still expects the remaining argument.

The inverse transformation is called uncurrying and turns a function that takes it arguments "one by one" into a function that takes its arguments "all at once" as a tuple.

Both transformations can be captured by families of higher-order functions. That is, for binary functions there is

```
curry :: ((a, b) -> c) -> (a -> b -> c)
curry    f             =  \x y -> f (x, y)

uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> ((a, b) -> c)
uncurry    f             =  \(x, y) -> f x y
```

For ternary functions there is

```
curry3 :: ((a, b, c) -> d) -> (a -> b -> c -> d)
curry3    f                =  \x y z -> f (x, y, z)

uncurry3 :: (a -> b -> c -> d) -> ((a, b, c) -> d)
uncurry3    f                  =  \(x, y, z) -> f x y z
```

And so forth.

Now let us have a look at your example:

```
2 * (\x y -> x * y) 2 3
```

Here you are multiplying the literal `2` with the result of an application of the function `(\x y -> x * y)` that multiplies its two arguments `x` and `y`. As you can see, this function already takes its arguments "one by one". Hence, it is already curried. So, what is meant in your tutorial if they ask to write a curried version of this expression is beyond me. What we could do is write an *uncurried* version by having the multiplication function takes it arguments "all at once": `(\(x, y) -> x * y)`. Then we get

```
2 * (\(x, y) -> x * y) (2, 3)
```

Now note that one could write `(\(x, y) -> x * y)` as `uncurry (*)`, which would give us

```
2 * uncurry (*) (2, 3)
```

If we also uncurry the first application (or actually applications, plural ;-)) of `(*)`, we yield

```
uncurry (*) (2, uncurry (*) (2, 3))
```

I doubt whether this was the intention behind the exercise in your tutorial, but I hope this provides you some insight in currying and uncurrying.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It certainly helped me understand the concept a little better.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning, the preceding question looks like this:

3) Write
`f:: Int -> Int -> Int  
f x y = 2*x+y  
f 2 3`  
using a lambda expression  
4) Write a curried version of this lambda expression

... 
The expression you see above is my answer to 3), thus I suspect this is what question 4 is asking for

Comment: @Steve: Perhaps it wanted you to write it out explicitly as multiple single-argument lambdas? e.g., `(\x -> (\y -> ...))`. That's... kind of pointless, and using the term "curried" wrong, but I suppose it emphasizes that the `(\x y -> ...)` form is equivalent (a shorthand, really).